# Youtube API Android Webview Not Working Correctly

Tags: javascript, android, youtube-api, android-webview, youtube-javascript-api

Unfortunately, I can't find any solutions on this site, on other way around I might have just seen it or used it but did not worked it properly. This young lad need your help guys. Can't really seem to get it to work.

I have this Android Application that uses Youtube-Api in most of the pages that displays the playlists of a youtube channel.

Like this (**Playlist Youtube-Api Query**)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {   
var playlist = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/******/playlists?v=2&alt=jsonc";
    $.getJSON(playlist,  function(response) {
      $.each(response.data.items, function(index, item) {
        $('#r_playlist').append('<div id="pl_title" class="playlists topBdr btmBdr" onclick=navlist_video("'+ item.id +'");><div class="pl_lb">' + item.title + '</div></div>');
      }); 
        $('.playlists').first().removeClass('topBdr');
        $('.playlists').last().removeClass('btmBdr');
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Here's the layout of my application
( **Home page** and **Playlists Page** )

The Home page shows the Featured videos in which uses the youtube query, example of query shown below. As for the Playlist Query it was shown above.

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&orderby=viewCount&max-results=5&q=xxxxxx
```

[image]

So my problem is, after navigating to navigation menu **Home -> Playlist -> Home** it shows the problem that I'm experiencing. 
So it was like, when I open the Android Application, It starts in HOME page then I navigate to Playlist Page, it also works. But **ONCE I navigate to Home Page Again**, it does not show the featured video anymore, I **navigate to playlist page**, it didn't show the playlist anymore. After I clear the data in android application and run the application again, it repeats the error.

[image]

Here is my android code.

```
package xxxxxx.xx;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView mWebView = null;
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webtest);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        try {
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://xxxxxxxx.com/android/index.html"); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if(url.endsWith("request")){
                   String redirectUrl = "http://xxxxxx.com/xxxxx/index.html";
                   view.loadUrl(redirectUrl);
                   return;
               } else if (url.startsWith("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request")) {
                   String redirectUrl = "http://xxxxxxx.com/android/index.html";
                   view.loadUrl(redirectUrl);
                   return;                 
               }
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        WebView mWebView = null;
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webtest);
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(mWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                    finish();
                    //mWebView.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Then my Javascript Code in Playlist:

```
<div id="r_playlist"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {   
var playlist = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/xxxxxxx/playlists?v=2&alt=jsonc";
    $.getJSON(playlist,  function(response) {
      $.each(response.data.items, function(index, item) {
        $('#r_playlist').append('<div id="pl_title" class="playlists topBdr btmBdr" onclick=navlist_video("'+ item.id +'");><div class="pl_lb">' + item.title + '</div></div>');
      }); 
        $('.playlists').first().removeClass('topBdr');
        $('.playlists').last().removeClass('btmBdr');
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this problem? Would be glad if someone helps me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally did it, well after experimenting a bit, I realized after going back and fort opening and uninstalling the application, for some reason when a Cache is stored or so it won't work. So what I did was put `view.clearCache(true);` after the page loads.

```
public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            view.clearCache(true);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

youtube vidoes having different different formats, andriod supports some formats only like 3gp,mp4 etc..., there is one solution, please install MXPlayer or VPlayer from google play with free of cost, now you can play the videos into MXPlayer directly using intent chooser, hope this will help to u.